# SEO: Sitemap & Multilingual website with different content

Tags: seo, sitemap, multilingual

I introduced English language on my website and it's ranking super bad, not sure why so trying to find a reason.

The content comes through `/en/` prefix in URL and 90% is different from main language, only few pages contain alternate hreflang meta tags. For now the `/en/` pages go in the same sitemap and I have a question:

Should I create a separate sitemap for `/en/` pages or it doesn't matter for Google if all the pages will come in one? Also for those pages that has alternate hreflang should I do same in sitemap or it's enough that I included them in meta tags?

Comment: As Google states, sitemap does not affect ranking, beyond the indirect benefit of having the whole website crawled and up-to-date in the index. I think you should split it if it goes beyond search engines' limits (Google is 50MB or 50K URLs), or its more convenient to you. https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2008/01/sitemaps-faqs#:~:text=A%20Sitemap%20does%20not%20affect%20the%20actual%20ranking%20of%20your%20pages.